# I am trying to get list of estimates from zoho books to zoho creator but its giving me error of data type mismatch

Tags: zoho, zohobooks

Please check this image for more details and code its simple code but i am getting datatype mismatch error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDYH6.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 2):

This is the common format to get list of records in zoho books module.

```
<variable> = zoho.books.getRecords(<module_name>, <org_ID>, <search>, <connection>);
```

**module_name**: Name of the module

**org_id**: Your organization id

**search**: specifies the values based on which the records will be filtered. You can specify an empty string or an empty map for this param, in which case all the records will be fetched

**connection**: Name of the connection

In order to get list of estimates Please do the following,

```
response = zoho.books.getRecords("Estimates", "54654632", "", "zbooks");
```

For further clarification refer this document https://www.zoho.com/deluge/help/books/fetch-records.html

If you have any other queries reach out to us at support@zohobooks.com

Answer (score 1):

The error shown on the screenshot is caused by the single quote you're using instead of double quotes (`"`).

You can use as following:

```
data = zoho.books.getRecords("Estimmates","OrganizationID","Connection");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are using single quotes for strings which Deluge intercepts as date or date-time strings. Use double quotes instead.